# Получение GET переменной из URL'а в JS

Tags: javascript, url, get

Как с помощью JS считать GET переменную которая находится в URL'е?
Например:

> http://site.ru?data=value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Выставим нужный URL для теста с помощью History API
history.replaceState({}, '', '/test?param=value&param2=42&keyonly');

// location.search === '?param=value&param2=42&keyonly'
var search = location.search.substr(1)
  .split('&') // разбиваем на параметры
  .reduce(function (res, a) { // разбираем пары ключ-значение
    var t = a.split('=');

    // нужно декодировать и ключ и значение, значения может не быть
    res[decodeURIComponent(t[0])] = t.length == 1 ? null : decodeURIComponent(t[1]);
    return res;
  }, {});

console.log(search); // {"param":"value","param2":"42","keyonly":null}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fed7vg9n/2/show/)

Comment: за `reduce` отдельный плюс)

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams). Данный пример считывает все переменные.

```
urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
params = {};

urlParams.forEach((p, key) => {
  params[key] = p;
});
```

Затем параметр `data` будет доступен в `params.data`.

Comment: `urlParams.get('data')` - не? И там ещё `getAll` есть.

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать объект `location` и его поля для доступа к `url`

```
// www.example.com?data=value
console.log(location.href); // www.example.com?data=value
console.log(location.search) // ?data=value
```

Comment: Т.е. тут ещё придётся разбивать все метки через символ &

Answer (score 0):

```
function $_GET(key) {
    var s = window.location.search;
    s = s.match(new RegExp(key + '=([^&=]+)'));
    return s ? s[1] : false;
};
```

Затем можно получать нужную переменную из вашего примера через

```
$_GET('data')
```

Касаемо URLSearchParams в одном из ответов, приведу [ссылку на caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=URLSearchParams).

Comment: Так себе код. Никаких экранирований - не для ключа, ни для значения, ни даже для регулярки.