# Как получить данные значения из адрессной строки через JS?

Tags: javascript

есть такой адресс сайта
https://site.ru/?UTM_SOURCE=youtube

Как получить значения UTM_SOURCE , т.е Youtube

Comment: Хотя вообще-то дубликат: [Получение GET переменной из URL'а в JS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/640107/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-get-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7-url%d0%b0-%d0%b2-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myParam = urlParams.get('UTM_SOURCE');
console.log(myParam);
```

(для Internet Explorer нужен [полифилл](https://github.com/ungap/url-search-params))

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так

```
function getUrlParam(parameter, defaultvalue){
    var urlparameter = defaultvalue;
    if(window.location.href.indexOf(parameter) > -1){
        urlparameter = getUrlVars()[parameter];
    }
    return urlparameter;
}
var source = getUrlParam('UTM_SOURCE ','Empty');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var p_url = location.search.substring(1);
var parametr = p_url.split("&");
var values = new Array();
for(i in parametr) {
var j=parametr[i].split("=");
values[j[0]]=unescape(j[1]);
}
```

Взято от [сюда](http://www.spravkaweb.ru/javascript/sovet/get) .